# Perl: Best way to have two conditions (of Linux shell commands) in the until loop

Tags: perl

I'm trying to find the best way to include 2 conditions of running Linux shell commands inside the while or until loop.

Pretty much, I can think of either of the following ways:

```
until ( (`who |grep user1`) && (`last -5 |grep user2`) ) {
        print "Waiting...\n";
        sleep(1);
}
```

or

```
open(my $command1, "who |"); open(my $command2, "last -5 |");
my $status1=1; my $status2=1;
until ( ($status1 == 0) && ($status2 == 0) ) {
        while(<$command1>) { $status1=0 if /user1/; }
        while(<$command2>) { $status2=0 if /user2/; }
        print "*** Waiting....... \n";
        sleep(1);
        close($command2); close($command1);
}
```

I guess there might be better Perl ways to do the above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl has its own `grep` function and it is usually better to use it than the shell command

```
until (grep(/user1/,`who`) && grep /user2/,`last -5`) {
    ...
}
```

but you can also pattern match against the raw output of a command, so `grep` might be superfluous

```
until (`who` =~ /user1/ && `last -5` =~ /user2/) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: mob - Excellent! Seems much better, and thank you very much.